# Where are the preferences in group policy in Windows 10?

Tags: group-policy, system-preferences, gpedit

I need to set preferences in group policy for date/time formats but I can't find preferences in the group policy editor.

[image]

I have obviously seen preferences in group policy in youtube videos etc but why is this totally missing from my group policy tool on Windows 10 professional?

I usually start group policy by typing gpedit in start menu but do I need to do something different?

Comment: Run `timedate.cpl` control panel.

Comment: @Biswapriyo I need to set policy so new accounts are created with the set format. Additionally I would hope that SysPrep wouldn't reset the policy if it was set through preferences because currently it resets it.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft **Group Policy Preferences** are limited to **Group** policy(Active Directory), you cannot configure as a **local** policy

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The long answer...

Edit the **Default** HKey_User registry keys to your desired state.

```
HKEY_USERS\Default User\Control Panel\International registry\sShortDate
```

[image: Time settings]

Then using gpedit.msc

```
prevent users from editing the registry key
```

[image]

And

```
Disallow user override of locale settings
```

[image]

Comment: I hope this helps.